# Conditional styling for post containers in The Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

My loop displays posts in two columns using this:

```
<?php
if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post();
 $count++;
?>
    <?php  if ($count == 1) : ?>
    <div class="home-ci-row">

    <div style="padding: 0px;" class="main-column-item-wrap">
    CONTENT OF POST : Title, Thumbnail, Excerpt... etc
    </div>

    <div class="home-ci-gap"></div><!-- /* the gap */ -->

    <?php elseif ($count == 2) : ?>    

   <div style="padding: 0px;" class="main-column-item-wrap">
   CONTENT OF POST : Title, Thumbnail, Excerpt... etc
   </div> <!-- main-column-item-wrap -->


</div><!-- /* home-ci-row*/ -->

<?php $count = 0; ?>

      <?php else : ?>
    // No posts
<?php endif; endwhile; endif; ?>
```

You can see that the `<div class="home-ci-row">` opens in the first count & closes in the second one `</div>`

so when my loop has an even number of posts works great, but with odd number it doesn't close the div

so My idea is this: If loop has even number

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hu4Ua.png]

If loop has odd number of posts

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjqzZ.png]

Comment: So, what have you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered on [WP Development StackExchange](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) by [fischi](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/15680/fischi)

Quoting from [his answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/90085/28550):

You could do this much easier. As you are making a layout that can be achieved by floats, there is no need to declare a Row every second time.

In my Code example I just youse the `$count` to determine the Class of the HTML-Element. In combination with the total Number of Posts displayed.

If the total number of posts `$wp_query->post_count` is reached by the `$count` AND the total number is odd, I give the Element the Class `fullwidth`. In the same way, I determine if it is the first or the second (see the IF-Statement).

All I need to do afterwards is output the corresponding Class for each HTML-Element in the Loop. Besides the Class, no Element is diffferent from each other.

I use the `Modulo` Operator in PHP ( `%` ) to determine odd/even. It delivers `1` if I use `$count % 2` and `$count` is odd. If you are not sure about this operator, read about it [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

So your code could look like this:

```
<?php
    $count = 0;
    if (have_posts()): while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        if ( ++$count == $wp_query->post_count && ( $wp_query->post_count % 2 ) == 1 ) {
            // if final count is reached AND final count is odd
            // full width item
            $postclass = "fullwidth";
            $opentag = '';
            $closingtag = '</div>';
        } else if ( ( $count % 2 ) == 1 ) {
            // if $count is odd it is the first item in a 'row'
            $postclass = "halfwidth first";
            $opentag = '<div class="home-ci-row">';
            $closingtag = '';
        } else {
            // second item in a row
            $postclass = "halfwidth second";
            $opentag = '';
            $closingtag = '</div>';
        }
?>
    <?php echo $opentag; ?>
    <div class="main-column-item-wrap <?php echo $postclass; ?>">
    CONTENT OF POST : Title, Thumbnail, Excerpt... etc
    </div><!-- main-column-item-wrap -->
    <?php echo $closingtag; ?>

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

By the way, you can do something like:

```
<?php
$count=0;
while(have_posts()){
    if($count%2==0){
        echo '<div class="home-ci-row">';
        //draw your left div here
    }else if($count%2==1){
        //draw your gap here
        //draw your right div here
        echo '</div>';
    }
    $count++;
}
//close div if count is an odd number
if($count%2==1) echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: you have to change `have_posts()` to what condition you need.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to swap to a for loop? Is this what you need?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfElements; $i++)
{ 
    //if (odd number) && (this is the last element)
    if (($i % 0 == 1) && ($i == $numberOfElements - 1))
    {
        //Special Case
    }
    else
    {
        //Normal Case
    }
}
```

Caveat: Watch out for errors, PHP isn't my strongest language